# XML Rendering Problems in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Здравстуйте, кто знает как это исправить? Ни конструктор ни пред-просмотр не работает а очень нужно. Спасибо.

[image: Rendering Problems]

Answer (score 1):

1. Испробуйте множество вариантов, в т.ч. смену железа.
2. Получите везде и всегда похожую проблему на разметках чуть более сложных чем `TextView`
3. Поймите, что этот инструмент работает плохо.
4. Поймите, что в т.ч. и поэтому им никто не пользуется.
5. Не пользуйтесь им.

Отображение разметки - очень сложная задача и нормально с ней справиться может только девайс/полноценный эмулятор. Предпросмоторщик намного менее мощная штука по сравнению с ними и, засим, в любом случае не сможет отобразить любую разметку. Засим пользоваться им не следует вовсе, ибо нектороые вещи он хоть и отобразит, но отобразит не верно.

Comment: Хорошо. А что тогда использовать?

Comment: @Вячеслав, девайс/эмулятор(студии или genymotion). Да, при каждом изменении разметки - перезапускать приложение

Comment: ..........Спасибо.